# Mac Environment Variable Not Detected If Using .sh File

Tags: bash, macos, sh

Mac Environment Variable works on Terminal but Not Detected If Using .sh File

I have script to build Unity libraries which using .sh and the script need Android sdk, so I add Adroid sdk path to environment variable.
In terminal, `echo $ANDROID_HOME` return the correct path, but if I echo from .sh file it returns nothing.

I have tried add the environment variable in `.bash_profile` or `.zshrc` or `.zprofile` . And everytime after add patch I run the `source` command like `source ~/.bash_profile`. And everytime I try `echo $ANDROID_HOME` it works but just in terminal. Using .sh file it returns nothing.

I also tried using `sudo` when will add the environment but no luck.

Beisdes `echo $ANDROID_HOME` (which return nothing/black) I also try to check the environment like this in `.sh` file and it goes into error echo

```
#!/bin/sh

# shellcheck disable=SC2039

. $(dirname $0)/common.sh

source "$PROJECT_ROOT/scripts/build.properties"

info "Starting build"
# Check for required settings
if [ -z "$ANDROID_HOME" ]; then
    echo "${RED}ERROR: ANDROID_HOME environment variable not set${NC}"
    echo "${RED}Please set the ANDROID_HOME environment variable to point to your android sdk${NC}"
    exit 1
fi
```

Btw, I run .sh from terminal in the script folder with `./script.sh` or sh `./script.sh`

I don't know if it help, but here is my environment variable in .bash_profile or .zshrc or .zprofile

```
if which rbenv > /dev/null; then eval "$(rbenv init -)"; fi

[[ -s "$HOME/.rvm/scripts/rvm" ]] && source "$HOME/.rvm/scripts/rvm" # Load RVM into a shell session *as a function*

# Setting PATH for Python 3.8
# The original version is saved in .bash_profile.pysave
PATH="/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/bin:${PATH}"
export PATH
eval "$(/opt/homebrew/bin/brew shellenv)"
export
ANDROID_HOME=/Applications/Unity/Hub/Editor/2021.1.17f1/PlaybackEngines/AndroidPlayer/SDK
export PATH=$PATH:$ANDROID_HOME/platform-tools
export PATH=$PATH:$ANDROID_HOME/tools
export PATH=$PATH:$ANDROID_HOME/tools/bin
export PATH=$PATH:$ANDROID_HOME/emulator
export
JAVA_HOME=/Applications/Unity/Hub/Editor/2021.1.17f1/PlaybackEngines/AndroidPlayer/OpenJDK
export PATH=$PATH:$JAVA_HOME/bin
export ANDROID_NDK_HOME=/Applications/Unity/Hub/Editor/2021.1.17f1/PlaybackEngines/AndroidPlayer/NDK
```

I'm using Mac Studio Apple M1 Max ,  MacOS 13.1 (22C65),

Comment: Are they on different lines than the `export`? BTW, you need `export` once per variable.

Comment: Where and how is your `.sh` file being run? From the terminal? From within a tool or editor or IDE?

Comment: What is the first line of the `.sh` file? the line that starts with `#!`?

Comment: @DiegoTorresMilano the `export` not in different line, idk why it shows like that.

Comment: @JonathanDodds  I run `.sh` from terminal in the script folder with `./script.sh` or `sh ./script.sh` . And the first line of `.sh` file is `#!/bin/sh` . I'm trying build `https://github.com/facebook/facebook-sdk-for-unity` if that help.

Comment: `sh` (Bourne shell) doesn't read the `.bash_profile`, `.zshrc`, or `.zprofile` files. Create a `.profile` file for `sh`.

Comment: @JonathanDodds I tried add path to new `.profile` but still same , simple `echo $ANDROID_HOME` return nothing/blank

Comment: I don't see how .bash_profile or .zshrc or .zprofile would be related to your question. If the variable `ANDROID_HOME` is already defined in the shell, from which you invoke your shell script, the variable will be be defined there (since the environment is inherited to child processes). Otherwise you will have to define it in your script or in one of the files sourced in the script (common.sh for instance). Do a `printenv ANDROID_HOME` in the **shell you are invoking your script from**. Do you see the variable?

Comment: Please simplify your code to create a **minimal** [mcve] - remove the various files being sourced (`. $(dirname $0)/common.sh` and `source "$PROJECT_ROOT/scripts/build.properties"` and `source "$HOME/.rvm/scripts/rvm"`) and evaled (`eval "$(rbenv init -)"` and `eval "$(/opt/homebrew/bin/brew shellenv)"`), that we can't see the contents of if they are not affecting the problem and if any of them actually IS affecting the problem then show it. For all we know one of those files has `unset ANDROID_HOME` or similar in it.

Comment: If the script that starts with `#!/bin/sh` in your question is stored in `script.sh` then remove the lines `. $(dirname $0)/common.sh`, `source "$PROJECT_ROOT/scripts/build.properties"`, and `info "Starting build"` from it, then execute these 3 commands from your command line: `echo "$ANDROID_HOME"; cat ./script.sh; ./script.sh` and then copy/paste you calling those commands and their output into your question as-is.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At the beginning of the script add line:

```
source ~/.zshrc
```

Answer (score 1):

When you say it doesn't work "from the .sh script," how is that script being run in the first place?

If you're running it *from within bash* or zsh, that ought to inherit the (correct) environment variables you've setup, unless they're gettin specifically overridden somewhere.  If that's what you're doing and it's not working, you have one problem.

However, if you're launching the scripts any other way (e.g. from another application, double-clicking them in Finder, or something else I haven't thought of), you have a different problem:  It wont work because neither the "parent" application nor `sh` (which is not bash/zsh) will be reading those files.  If that's the issue you're having, you need to either:

1. Set things up so that your .sh script files are (directly or indirectly) sourcing the environment file.  Bourne Shell (`sh`), `bash`, and `zsh` all look source slightly different configuration files depending the context in which they're being executed (mostly, if it's a login shell or not), so you need to be clear on which shell(s) you're using, and setup the configuration accordingly.
2. Your other option is to try to set the desired variables on a system-wide (or login-session-wide) basis, so that they're present for all applications, whether shells are involved or not.  If that's your situation, you go down an entirely different route using `launchctl setenv`, which I just wrote up here https://www.reddit.com/r/MacOS/comments/12ryky5/comment/k3qcjf3/ (and can copy over to SO if desired.)

Answer (score 0):

Your script use [bash](/questions/tagged/bash): you use these tests: `[[ ]]`.

So never run a `bash` script with `sh` shell, it's not the same.

The recommended way if to add a *shebang* at the first line, like:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash
```

then

```
chmod +x script.sh
```

now

```
./script.sh
```

the problem should be fixed. If not, give us the error(s).

Comment: The OP hasn't shown the .sh file. The file shown is probably the .bash_profile

Comment: the first line of .sh file is #!/bin/sh. chmod not help. And like I said in .sh file `echo $ANDROID_HOME` return or show nothing.

Comment: I ask you to **change the shebang** `/bin/sh` for bash

Comment: @GillesQuénot yes, I've just tried that and same thing return nothing `echo $ANDROID_HOME`